# When I join only the flickering happening

Tags: node-editor

[image]

[image]

As it is, the Altar is perfect. But when I join it to the wall it flickers. First Altar did not have faces at the back and the back wall was just plane. So I put faces at the back of the Altar and made the back wall 3D too (not just solidify) But it is still happening.
Can someone help me with this please.
Thanks.

Comment: May be you have a mirror modifier on your main object, but not on the second, it's just symmertical. After you join it to the main object, all of its face will be double, because the modifier. Apply the modifier before the joining or delete the half of the second mesh.

Comment: Thanks for the reply.First I used mirror modifier to make the cross. But then I got worse result. When I joined it to the wall, half the cross (the image part) totally disappeared. So this time I made the whole cross, and now when joined, it is flickering. I even tried cutting a whole with boolean and fit the cross inside it. Still it is flickering. There are no double vertices either.

Comment: I meant 'cut a hole' with boolean.